# skpy to send a message to a group with user mention

Tags: python, message, skype, mention

I need to mention particular user in the message that I sent to a group in Skype. I can send the message easily with the skpy but can't figure it out how to mention someone in the message.

```
sk=Skype("userid","paasword")
SendMsgTo=sk.chats["group-id"]
SendMsgTo.sendMsg("hello")
```

there is this sendRaw() thing in skpy which I think I'll have to use, but can't figure it out how to use.

I am new to python and finding my way through the google and the great community of stackoverflow and the similar. So a little help will greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SendMsgTo.sendMsg('<at id="8:USER_ID">USER_NAME</at> ', rich=True)
```

also, if you don't know USER_ID use the `SendMsgTo.userIds` to find all USER_ID in the group

Comment: thanks! do you know how to use the **@all** mention? I tried `"<at id=\"*\">all</at> "` didn't work for me

Comment: I think, you can use `SendMsgTo.sendMsg('<at id="*">all</at>' , rich=True) `

Comment: Thanks, I added the `rich=True`, that solved the issue.